# Ways to connect a Java Application to Microsoft CRM 2013 or 2016

Tags: java, .net, rest, soap, dynamics-crm

I want to integrate a java application with Microsoft CRM 2013.For that i have seen that MS CRM 2013 provides Rest as well as SOAP web services but after a lot of efforts that was in vain so my questions are these?

Is it true that MS CRM 2013(and/or 2016) REST service are no more exposed to external application?

For the SOAP web service.My CRM authentication is via Active directory(on premise authentication).For that i did not find a single ressource on the net how to do that.What i found is only for MS CRM 2011

Some links on the net advice to have an installed dotnet service or application that use the MS CRM 2013 to connect to the CRM and then create a webservice that will be a proxy between my java application and the MS CRM .Is this the only/best  way to do that?

thnaks in advance.

Comment: Some years ago on a project I had to do the same thing, we where installing the java part, and another company was installing the CRM. They where specialist in microsoft CRM, and they did say that a proxy application for us to connect to was the way to go. So if we assume they where good at there job (and I don't see why not), it seems to be the best way.

Answer (score 2):

**CRM 2013**

The support isnt as a good for non-.Net projects.

As a .Net developer when using the Organization Service (SOAP), I use the SDK API which simplifies development.

The Organization Data (Rest) service is typically used in JavaScript from within CRM.

The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327838(v=crm.6).aspx) suggests using the WSDL to connect to the Organization Service

> You can also access data from Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 using the
>   Web Services Description Language (WSDL) from the web service.

Oddly the MSDN for 2013 doesn't have any further explanation. However the older [2011](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509052(v=crm.5).aspx) articles provide further elaboration.

> While the most common style of development for Microsoft Dynamics CRM
>   2011 is using the SOAP endpoint with early or late bound types, there
>   are situations where you wish to use the Web Services Description
>   Language (WSDL) endpoint directly. This is a light-weight endpoint
>   that can be used from non-.NET languages. You can download the WSDL
>   from the developer resources page. For more information, see [Download
>   the Endpoints Using the Dynamics CRM Developer Resources Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309401(v=crm.6).aspx). For
>   more information about Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)
>   interoperability, see [Web Service Interoperability](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/webservicesinterop.aspx).
>
> The SDK download package contains sample code for authentication and
>   use of the WSDL endpoint for Active Directory, Active Directory with
>   Claims, Online (both Microsoft account and Microsoft Office 365), and
>   for Internet-facing deployment (IFD). This is located in the
>   SDK\SampleCode\CS\WsdlBasedProxies folder. For another example of a
>   client application that uses web services only, see this example in
>   the MSDN Code Samples Gallery: [CRM Online 2011 WebServices - SOAP Only
>   Client](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/crm-online-2011-webservices-14913a16).

There is also this [2011](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602979.aspx) sample.

**CRM 2016**

I don't believe the picture for the Organization Service (SOAP) or the Organization Data (Rest) has changed much.

However, there is now the new [Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt593051.aspx) which promises better support.

> The Web API, which is new for Microsoft Dynamics 365 (online &
>   on-premises), provides a development experience that can be used
>   across a wide variety of programming languages, platforms, and
>   devices. The Web API implements the OData (Open Data Protocol),
>   version 4.0, an OASIS standard for building and consuming RESTful APIs
>   over rich data sources.

Comment: This really helps. I'm also researching this and found this open source Microsoft Project [azure-activedirectory-library](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android), which seems to help with Java based authentication (but only with CRM 2016(?), because of the mentioning of Web API(?)).

If you have any more information on how to set up a Java based interface to Dynamics CRM 2013 on premise, this is highly appreciated.